# C programming, fscanf only inputs the last element

Tags: c, file, linked-list

I'm trying to get multiple elements from a file and put it in my array linked list but it only inputs the last element of the file.

Inside the file is

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

Here's my code

```
typedef struct node{
    int elem;
    struct node *next;
}node;

void insert(node **a)
{
    int temp,elem;
    node *tempstruct;
    tempstruct = (*node)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    FILE *fp;
    if(fp = fopen("input.txt","r")){
        while(fscanf(fp,"%d",&elem)==1){
            temp = elem%10;
            tempstruct->elem = elem;
            tempstruct->next = a[temp];
            a[temp] = tempstruct;
        }
    }
}
```

The expected output should be

```
A[0]   10
A[1]   11   1
A[2]   12   2 
A[3]   13   3 
A[4]   14   4
A[5]   15   5 
A[6]   16   6
A[7]   17   7
A[8]   18   8
A[9]   19   9
```

But What i get is

```
A[0]   19
A[1]   19
A[2]   19
A[3]   19
A[4]   19
A[5]   19
A[6]   19
A[7]   19
A[8]   19
A[9]   19
```

I am trying to put elements in the indexes corresponding to their ones digit, but all it puts is the last element which is 19.

Comment: Your code can't compile. E.g `(*node)`, `temp = %elem;`

Comment: Try to avoid type casting the return value of malloc.

Comment: You're attempting to debug too much.  First, understand how to read the data from the file.  Second, figure out how to assign these items to the `node`'s

Comment: oops sorry about that it's temp = elem%10 to get the index for ones digits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only call `malloc` a single time so you end up with a situation where all elements in the array points to the same object. Instead you should call `malloc` for each succesful scan.

Like:

```
void insert(node **a)
{
    int temp,elem;
    node *tempstruct;
    FILE *fp;
    if(fp = fopen("input.txt","r")){
        while(fscanf(fp,"%d",&elem)==1){
            tempstruct = malloc(sizeof(struct node));  // malloc inside the loop
            temp = elem % 10;      // Find the index where the new object shall be added
            tempstruct->elem = elem;
            tempstruct->next = a[temp];
            a[temp] = tempstruct;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code  is precarious: It is not clear how mush of `a[]` is valid.

Comment: @chux True. Unfortunately OP never posted a complete code example. However, from the "expected output" it seems fair to assume that `a[]` has 10 elements, i.e. 10 linked lists where data is sorted based on the last digit of data.